# He is unruly and unrestrained

Tags: word-choice

When his parents are out of town, my nephew has freedom. He hangs around with his friends until very late. He does all kinds of crazy things like flipping a light switch on and off for fifteen minutes and skateboarding on a highway. I am going to describe him.

(1) He is unruly and unrestrained.

(2) His behavior is unruly and unrestrained.

Am I using the right adjectives?

Comment: Those are good adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

Your adjectives

> **unruly**
>   **unrestrained**

are good, a few additional ones might be

> misbehaved
>   wild
>   crazy
>   undisciplined *(if he doesn't listen to you)*
>   dangerous *(skateboarding on the highway)*